# Double free or corruption of a variable in a function called from OpenMP loop

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I have a parallel loop that calls a function "interpol" to fill a local variable "Velocity" by multiplying for example "velField" by some coofficient.:

```
void foo(){

    //Shared pointer to the source
    VectorField* velField = Source.getPointer();
    #pragma omp parallel shared( velField )
    {
        //private variable Velocity 
        matrixdouble Velocity(1,3);

    #pragma omp for schedule(auto)
        for (unsigned i=0;i< NbNodes; ++i)
        {

                Velocity = interpol(*velField);

        }
    }
}
```

and

```
matrixdouble interpol(VectorField& velField ){
    matrixdouble Result(1,3);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            Result(i,j) = velField(i,j) * 0.25;

    //here the program stops
    return Result;

}
```

But the programm always fails with a message "double free or corruption (fasttop)" when you return the "Result" in the function "interpol". And with 20 threads it gives 18 the same addresses where it fails and two other ones that are also the same.

`: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ebcb20 ***
: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ebcb20 ***
: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ebca40 ***
: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ebca40 ***
: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ebca40 ***
: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ebca40 ***
: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ebca40 ***
: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x0000000000ebca40 ***`
...

So my question is: is the variable "Result" in the function "interpol" shared?

```
 template<typename T> class Matrix
{
    public:
        // Constructors & Destructors.
        inline Matrix();
        inline Matrix(const Matrix<T> & original);
        inline Matrix(const unsigned rows, const unsigned cols);
        inline Matrix(const unsigned rows, const unsigned cols, const T val);
        inline Matrix(const unsigned rows, const unsigned cols, T * pdata);
        inline ~Matrix();
        // Resize and reshape functions
        inline void resize(const unsigned rows, const unsigned cols);
        inline void reshape(const unsigned rows, const unsigned cols, const T & pad = 0);
        void fill(const T val);
        inline Matrix<T> & reference(const Matrix<T> & original);
        inline Matrix<T> & operator=(const Matrix<T> & original);
        Matrix<T> & operator+=(const Matrix<T> & m2);
        Matrix<T> & operator-=(const Matrix<T> & m2);
        Matrix<T> & operator*=(const double d);
        inline Matrix<T> copy() const throw (std::runtime_error);
        void apply(T (*f)(T));
        Matrix<T> applyCopy(T (*f)(T)) const;
        inline unsigned getRows() const;
        inline unsigned getCols() const;
        inline unsigned getSize() const;
        inline T * getData() const;
        inline void setName(std::string name);
        inline std::string getName() const;
        inline const T & operator()(const unsigned row, const unsigned col) const;
        inline T & operator()(const unsigned row, const unsigned col);
        inline int operator==(const Matrix<T> & right) const;
        inline void invert() throw ();
        inline void addColToCol(const unsigned col1, const Matrix<T> & m2, const unsigned col2);
        inline void addVecToCol(const unsigned col1, const Vector<T> & v2);
        inline void addVecToRow(const unsigned col1, const Vector<T> & v2);
        inline void transpose();
        Matrix<T> transposeCopy();
        Vector<T> toVector() const throw (std::logic_error);
        Vector<T> colToVector(const unsigned col) const;
        Vector<T> rowToVector(const unsigned row) const;
        void vectorToCol(const unsigned col, const Vector<T> & v);
        void vectorToRow(const unsigned row, const Vector<T> & v);
        inline void times(const Matrix<T> & m, const Vector<T> & v);
        void AXPY(T alpha, const Matrix<T> & X) throw ();
        void AXPY_ColToCol(const unsigned col1, const Matrix<T> & X, const unsigned col2,
                T alpha) throw ();
        void GEMM(T alpha, const Matrix<T> & A, const Matrix<T> & B, T beta) throw ();
        void GEMM(T alpha, const DiagMatrix<T> & D, const Matrix<T> & B, T beta) throw ();
        void SYMM(T alpha, const Matrix<T> & A, const Matrix<T> & B, T beta) throw ();
        Vector<std::complex<T> > EigenValues() throw ();
        Matrix<T> subMatrix(const unsigned row1, const unsigned row2, const unsigned col1,
                const unsigned col2) const throw ();
    private:
        ReferenceMatrix<T> * data_;
};
```

and a class of a private variable

```
  template<typename T> class ReferenceMatrix
{
    public:
        ReferenceMatrix();
        ReferenceMatrix(const unsigned rows, const unsigned cols);
        ReferenceMatrix(const unsigned rows, const unsigned cols, T * pdata);
        ~ReferenceMatrix();
        inline void resize(const unsigned rows, const unsigned cols);
        inline void reshape(const unsigned rows, const unsigned cols, const T & pad);
        inline ReferenceMatrix<T> * reference();
        inline void dereference();
        inline unsigned getRows() const;
        inline unsigned getCols() const;
        inline unsigned getSize() const;
        inline T * getData() const;
        inline void setName(std::string name);
        inline std::string getName() const;
        inline const T & operator()(const unsigned & row, const unsigned & col) const;
        inline T & operator()(const unsigned & row, const unsigned & col);
        void transpose();
    private:
        unsigned rows_, cols_, size_;
        unsigned reference_count_;
        bool user_mem_management_; // deallocation done by user
        T * data_;
        std::string name_;
};
```

And the constructor for reference matrix is below, meaning that it is dynamically allocated

```
   template<typename T> ReferenceMatrix<T>::ReferenceMatrix(const unsigned rows,
        const unsigned cols)
{
    // Using namespace & using directives.
    using namespace std;

    // Create a new (rows by cols) Matrix.

    if (((rows_ = rows) > 0) & ((cols_ = cols) > 0))
    {
        size_ = rows_ * cols_;
        user_mem_management_ = false;
        data_ = new T[size_];
        reference_count_ = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        size_ = 0;
        user_mem_management_ = false;
        data_ = 0;
        reference_count_ = 1;
    }
    name_ = "";
}
```

Comment: What is `Source`? What is `matrixDouble`? Does `matrixDouble` follow [the rules of three, five or zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)?

Comment: **Source** is a class that contains a private variable of a type **VectorField**, so getPointer() returns a pointer to a private variable of the Sourse. **matrixDouble** is a class that represents 2D matrix with a 1D array. Rules of five in all

Comment: And that array in `matrixDouble`, is it dynamically allocated? Do you have a copy- or move- constructor? Does the copy-constructor copy only the pointer or does it create a new array and copy it? Because this is most likely a problem with the copy- or move-constructor.

Comment: yes, dynamically allocated, has a copy constructor that creates a new array and copies into it with memcpy

Comment: the program fails at the 'dereference' step of the Result when you return it if you follow the debugger.

Comment: Can you please *show* us the class?

Comment: see the declaration of the class Matrix (matrixdouble = Matrix<double>) above in the question formulation. any particular function that can be interresting to see in this class?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95445/discussion-between-vyacheslav-korchagin-and-joachim-pileborg).

Comment: `Matrix` doesn't follow the "rule of five", and `ReferenceMatrix` doesn't even follow the "rule of three".

Comment: molbdnilo, then I was wrong. You also think that the problem is there?